# To decrypt Password using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query i want to decrypt the password i tried but it displays null.I refer this example "http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/encrypt-and-decrypt-text-in-sql-server-2008" to my query.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
 SELECT UserID, UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserLoginID,DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('8', UserPassword) AS PASS, EmailID, ContactNo, PositionInOrg,CustomerID FROM Users
```

Comment: It must never be possible to decrypt a password.

Comment: You should always encrypt passwords using a one way algorithm (i.e. impossible to decrypt) then compare the encrypted values.